# Troubleshoot possible dead motherboard or PSU on 2 PC

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

I have a problem with 2 computers. Both are completely dead and don't respond when clicking the Power button. The computers worked fine for about a year ago, but hasn't been used since. I suspected they died from lighting perhaps, but they've been stored at two different locations. This is not my computers, I'm just troubleshooting.

What I've tried:

- Disconnected everything from the motherboard(s) except PSU and cables to the power button
- I jump started both PSU's and the fan started on both of them
- Tried both PSU in both computers, same result
- Checked several times that the power button wire is connected to the correct PINS on the motherboard
- Also tried to jump start the motherboard on the power pin, but nothing happened
- The motherboard LED lights so I guess the PSU seem to work

My conclusion is that both motherboards are dead. Any other way I can test the motherboards to verify? 
I'd also like to test the PSUs properly but don't have a multimeter or a PSU tester at the moment

Comment: Your best bet would be to get a "known-good" PSU and eliminating all the unknowns.

Comment: Thanks bluefog - I'll see if I can come up with a working PSU or a testing device for properly testing it.

Answer (score 2):

Are the motherboards off-the-shelf products you can buy individually (and thus would have their manuals available online from the Internet) or some integrated ones (most likely inside a "branded" computer such as a Dell, HP, or some other big manufacturer - these may have limited availability for the motherboard manuals)?

If you can find a manual based on the motherboard type code (or equiv.), you might want to check out if the boards have some diagnostics integrated - I've seen many with some LEDs or other lights that have different meanings based on their color, lit or not and at what stage they are lit.

If you suspect the boards may be faulty because of lightning or some other electrical mayhem, you could check the capacitors if they seem "bloated" on the top, once I managed to save a board by replacing a blown capacitor component after a PSU failure (which was caused by lightning as well).

The fact that the PSU fan kicks off or a light lits up on the motherboard doesn't necessarily yet mean the PSU is supplying correct voltage, to check this you'd need some additional equipment though (that multimeter or some other reliable testing device).

Comment: Thanks ka79. The computers are non-branded so I will check for the mobo manuals. I couldn't find any diagnostics LEDs except for the green one, so I think it uses the speaker for troubleshooting during POST. Thanks for the tip regarding the capacitor, I will take a look. You're right, I should test the PSUs properly. Thanks for all help so far! The computers are at another location so I'll troubleshoot more next week. I'll also try to get a device/multimeter for testing the PSU. Upvoted for good troubleshooting tips

Answer (score 1):

In my 8 years as a IT tech I'v found that jump starting a PSU by shorting the green and any one of the black connectors on the 24pin cable, assuming the fan spins, does NOT mean the PSU works. IE it doesnt mean the PSU can supply enough amps to power on the system.

I'v 'revived' a few boards that were suspected dead by doing the following:

Remove all RAM,GPU's,etc so you just have the motherboard connected to the PSU (please use a known working unit to save time / trouble) , also plug a fan into a fan header for visual observation, but the PSU fan should spin continuously and not spin up and down.

Short the connectors mentioned and and look for some life, if there is no life, remove power cable, short motherboard power pins to discharge any current, install known working RAM and ideally a motherboard speaker, power unit back up and hope the fans spins / the board beeps (usually 1 long loud beep for RAM).

If that is the case, power off, discharge, install CPU+cooler and power it back on.

From there I'd test RAM / RAM slots with Memtest86,test HDD with HDSentinal,before proceeding to install Windows. Or you can try boot straight to the OS and hope for the best, depending on time constraints.